# API route permissions using an express-jwt-permissions guard on node.js

Tags: node.js, authentication, permissions, jwt, express-jwt

I am attempting to use express-jwt-permissions to protect an API route and I am unable to use the guard syntax "guard.check('user')". I have successfully used [express-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt) which express-jwt-permissions builds upon.

An interesting fact is that express-jwt requires the JWT_SECRET to be assigned to it, whereas there are no instruction on the [express-jwt-permissions](https://github.com/MichielDeMey/express-jwt-permissions) docs to understand this interplay or perhaps there is some example missing?

My current code is as follows:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////
// auth.ts - Auth and set user permissions
/////////////////////////////////////////////
router.post('/', async (request, response, next) => {
    const {email, password} = request.body

    try {
        // Authenticate
        const user = await authenticate(email, password)
        user.permissions = ['user'] // set the express-jwt-permissions here

        // Create JWT token
        let token = jwt.sign(user.toJSON(), process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
            expiresIn: '60m'
        })

        let {iat, exp} = jwtDecode(token)

        // Respond with token
        response.status(HttpStatus.OK).send({iat, exp, token})


...
```

I successfully retrieved a JWT token from the 'api/auth' endpoint.

```
{
    "iat": 1559650778,
    "exp": 1559654378,
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJwZXJtaXNzaW9ucyI6WyJ1c2VyIl0sIl9pZCI6IjVjZjUyZjc1NDA4MTk0YWI1MGZlMWNkNiIsIm5hbWUiOiJHYXJ5IFBhbHVrIiwiZW1haWwiOiJnYXJ5QHBsdWdpbi5pbyIsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiZ2FyeSIsInBhc3N3b3JkIjoiJDJhJDEwJEt1U1NUQXowd1MxNU5tRjRVQjZQb2VMTC5Ya1phZkc5Sm9xVkVRWnZZcHFkTFNrZXliTU1lIiwidXBkYXRlZEF0IjoiMjAxOS0wNi0wM1QxNDozMjoyMS4zMDlaIiwiY3JlYXRlZEF0IjoiMjAxOS0wNi0wM1QxNDozMjoyMS4zMDlaIiwiX192IjowLCJpYXQiOjE1NTk2NTA3NzgsImV4cCI6MTU1OTY1NDM3OH0.qnfH_OHq2YqaKCRIbwtw788SQC51F8PJESRCf3Nlrak"
}
```

I then attempted to authorize with combinations of Bearer Token, OAuth2, prepending token with/without 'jwt ' etc, but nothing seems to get past the route guard on 'api/registry'.

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////
// server.ts - API auth routes
/////////////////////////////////////////////
server.use(
    '/api/registry',
    guard.check('user'),
    require('./api/v1/registry')
)

server.use('/api/auth', require('./api/v1/auth'))


...
```

Result:

```
{
    "name": "UnauthorizedError",
    "message": "user object \"user\" was not found. Check your configuration.",
    "code": "user_object_not_found",
    "status": 403,
    "inner": {
        "message": "user object \"user\" was not found. Check your configuration."
    }
}
```

The expected result would be that I can make an API call to '/api/registry' with the JWT token as a bearer token / OAuth2? and that should let me pass the route guard.

Thanks

Comment: can you share your check method ? from there I think I got something on how your try to very the token ?